# Re-sizing a Hash Table

Tags: java, hashtable

I am trying to re-size a `hash table`. I find that my logic is correct, but the code is all wrong. I know that when adding elements into a hash table you must consider the `load factor`, if the `load factor` is exceeded, the capacity doubles.

Example. `Size = 3, Capacity = 5`. 
`Load Factor = 5 * 0.75 = 3.75` 
If we add an element `Size = 4`, which exceeds the `load factor`, thus `Capacity = 10`. 
However, I am return the original `Capacity`.

```
/**
* size if load >.75 or < .5
*/
private void resize(int newCap)
{
  //   
   double capacity = buckets.length * 0.75;
   //System.out.println(capacity);
   if (currentSize > capacity) {
       int C = buckets.length * 2;
       newCap = C
       //System.out.println(C);
   }
}

/**
 * Gets the length of the array backing this HashSet
 * @return the length of the array backing this HashSet
 */
public int getCap()
{
  //
   int capac = buckets.cap
   resize(capac);
   return capac;
}
```

Comment: Is it not necessary in your hash table implementation to re-add every item stored in the table upon resize?

Comment: It is actually! I've been attack this problem incorrectly.. ahh thanks @SimonT

Answer (score 0):

`newCap = C` in method `resize` will not change the value of `capac`

You should be returning the `newCap` from `resize` method

```
/**
* size if load >.75 or < .5
*/
private int resize(int newCap)
{
  //   
   double capacity = buckets.length * 0.75;
   //System.out.println(capacity);
   if (currentSize > capacity) {
       int C = buckets.length * 2;
       return C;
       //System.out.println(C);
   }
   return newCap;
}

/**
 * Gets the length of the array backing this HashSet
 * @return the length of the array backing this HashSet
 */
public int getCap()
{
  //
   int capac = buckets.cap;
   capac = resize(capac);
   return capac;
}
```

In java, there is always pass-by-value. See a relevant discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662288/can-i-pass-a-primitive-type-by-reference-in-java)

Edit: Changed the return type as rightly pointed out.

Comment: However; you cannot return a value from a method whose type is Void.

Comment: Right. But I hope you got the problem